# My Product Catalog Weight (decimal) Will Not Update to Decimal Amount

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net 3.5 ecommerce app the product catalog admin area has gridview to edit product table. The weight field is a decimal and will not update to a decimal but rounds off to the nearest integer.

```
        string weight = ((TextBox)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("weightTextBox")).Text;


    // Update an existing product
public static bool UpdateProduct(string productId, string name, string description, string weight, string price, string Thumbnail, string Image, string Inventory, string PromoFront, string Rank)
{
    // get a configured DbCommand object
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
    // set the stored procedure name
    comm.CommandText = "CatalogUpdateProduct";
     ....
    //create a new parameter
    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@Weight";
    param.Value = weight;
    param.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);
     ....
    // result will represent the number of changed rows
    int result = -1;
    try
    {
        // execute the stored procedure
        result = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm);
    }
    catch
    {
        // any errors are logged in GenericDataAccess, we ignore them here
    }
    // result will be 1 in case of success 
    return (result != -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Weight is a `decimal`, why does your Update method accept weight as a `string`? This is just asking for trouble as you are not enforcing any constraints in your code.

Change your method signature so that it requires specific data types, then perform your casting before you call UpdateProduct. If anything, this will make it much easier to test/maintain.

In your case you would do:

```
decimal weight = 
Decimal.Parse((TextBox)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("weightTextBox")).Text);
```

Comment: Good points. I tried your casting and no joy. But thanks for getting me onto best practices.  I inserted an extra parenthesis to enclose the entire statement.         decimal weight = Decimal.Parse(((TextBox)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("weightTextBox")).Text);